# Pega Platform Personal edition 8.6 404 error on login page

Tags: java, database, postgresql, tomcat, pega

I have successfully installed personal edition 8.6 as per the directions provided on pdn. But application isn't opening on startup. After I try to launch login I'm getting the following error on the browser

> Access Error: 404 -- Not Found
>
> Cannot open document for: /prweb/PRServlet

I tried shut down the personal edition and restart it as per directions provided on pdn but nothing seems to work, getting the same error. I installed personal edition again after deleting the existing files and tried, it successfully installs but fail to startup and login.

Answer (score 3):

An Icon would have been created on your desktop, `Pega Platform 8.6.0 Startup`.

Double click in this icon would start `Tomcat` server, `Postgresql` server and loads `prweb` on Tomcat server. This can take some time. It depends on the PC RAM also.

You can confirm this by checking the logs if everything went perfect or not.

To see the path of the logs, go to the folder where you extracted the Pega tool and go to `PRPCPersonalEdition\tomcat\logs`.

Then open `Catelina.[Date].log` file.

Go to the end of the file and check if `Server startup in 214307 ms` sentence present or not. If this is present then you can click on icon `Pega Platform 8.6.0 Login`.

If this sentence is not present then a error would be there in the logs. Try to resolve that error.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen similar issue while some other process was listening on port 8080 before I launched Pega. In that case, in PRPCPersonalEdition\tomcat\logs\catalina.[Date].log we can see exception "*Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind*".

The easiest solution is to change the default port used by Pega Personal Edition from 8080 to, for example, 8081. In order to do so - open  PRPCPersonalEdition\tomcat\conf\server.xml and set the new port number in the following element:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       connectionTimeout="20000"
       redirectPort="9443" />
```

Then start/restart Pega with "Pega Platform 8.6.0 Startup" shortcut.
Once the startup is completed, Pega login page should be available at http://localhost:8081/prweb/PRServlet